# I have an issue when using jquery to load a .DAE file into a target div

Tags: jquery

When using jquery to load a 3D model converted to a .DAE file into a target div in the centre of the page, a list of words and numbers appear in the div instead of the 3D model.

I am trying to use jquery to load 3D models (.DAE files) into a target div when one of the buttons in the bottom left is pressed, then when the other is pressed I want the model displayed in the div to change.

Screenshots of when both buttons are pressed can be seen below. - the 3D model should be displayed in the div instead of the list of text that appears.

[Screenshot of when Load Blood Cell button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQVS7.png)

[Screenshot of when Load Egg Cell button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqTMr.png)

The code I am using can be seen below. Any help is greately appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#LBC').click(function() {
    $('#target').load('blood.DAE');
});

$('#LEC').click(function() {
    $('#target').load('egg2.DAE');

});

});
</script>

<title>Visualising Cells</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<script>

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;


var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500 );
camera.position.z = 0.16;
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
scene.add(camera);


var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width,height); 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene,camera);
renderer.setClearColor("rgb(181,181,181)");

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
        scene.add(light);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(0, 0, 0.14);
        scene.add(light);



var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.load('blood.DAE', function (collada) {

            object = collada.scene;
            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.y = 0;
            object.position.z = 0;
            object.updateMatrix();

            }
            );



document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
console.log("Up Arrow Pressed");
console.log(camera.position.z);
if (event.keyCode == 38) {

    if (camera.position.z >= 0.1) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.01;

    }

}

else if (event.keyCode == 40) {

    console.log("Down Arrow Pressed")

    if (camera.position.z < 0.2) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.01;
    }

    }
}, true);

render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

object.rotation.x += 0.01;
object.rotation.y += 0.01;


renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
        render();

</script>


<div class="float-btn">
<button type="button" id="LBC">Load Red Blood Cell</button>
<button type="button" id="LEC">Load Egg Cell</button>
</div>

<div class="float-txt">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 18px">
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
<h1>Visualising Microscopic Cells</h1>
</div>

<div class="instructions">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 16px">
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
<h2>Instructions</h2>
</div>

<div class="instruction-txt">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 14px">
<p><u>Zoom In:</u> <strong>Up Arrow</strong> <br><u>Zoom Out:</u> <strong>Down Arrow</strong></br></p>
</div>

<div class="Model-Location" id="target">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: third time today you've asked the same question. If you are following some tutorial or something regarding use of `.dae` files suggest you insert more information. Those are not a normal web format that I am aware of and as others have mentioned

Comment: @charlietfl So is there another file format i could try, possibly .obj?

Comment: no idea what you are trying to do with this file, or what it's structure is

Comment: This code is completely screwed up.  You load the .dae in with loader.load and update the scene's position and matrix, but then dont put in in the scene. Do this with scene.add(object) and the update matrix. Then delete the code in the click events you have, that is just garbage, and instead call the code that uses the loader.load function.

Comment: @charlietfl The only reason I posted a similar question was because one person complained in the first question that i didn't explain the problem with the text appearing in the div, so that's what i did in this question.

Comment: so update that question ...don't create 3 the same day that are all variations of the same thing

Comment: @fluffybunny that's probuably because i'm a complete novice using tutorials on youtube to try and complete this project for school. The code is doing what i need it too, but all i need to know is why all the text is appearing instead of the model. If you dont know why it doesnt work, is their another file type i could try and use instead of .dae?

Comment: @fluffybunny i appreciate your patience. How would i go about calling the code that uses the loader.load function? (Once again i'm a novice thats been doing this for a week.)

Comment: Put the collada loader code in the event handler and get rid of the $(target) crap.  Also, gotta add scene.add(object) in the loader.load callback.